# hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto configuration

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am using hibernate with Oracle.
Due to some bureaucratic and unchangeable issues, I am sharing a oracle schema with someone else. That means some tables are used by me, and some other tables are used by someone else.

I would like to use `"hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" = "create-drop"`  in this case, but I am afraid **ALL** tables would be deleted, including the ones that do not belong to me.

Am I correct?  What are the options?

Comment: You could use a migration framework where you have control over the database migrations. For example flyway: http://flywaydb.org. `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` is more like "I do what I want ...".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create will drop and create **only** tables that are mapped by your hibernate instance. All other tables (unmapped) will be **untouched**.

Comment: Really?!? That's awesome! Are you 100% sure?

Comment: @guilhermecgs If you have hbms or annotations for those tables (which you dont want to touch), it will definitely delete them as well.

Answer (score 1):

It won't, hibernate doesn't create/drop schemas, thus it doesn't know other tables. Everything it works is in their configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have defined mappings for those tables, it will be recreated.

The other options are set `hibernate.hbm2dll.auto=update` or even remove it completely. As you have `create-drop` it will clear the schema at the end of session. If you want to start with a new schema every single time you start the application, you may need to write additional cleanup queries and call them at the startup.

Answer (score 0):

```
"hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" = "create-drop"
```

I used this option to recreate my tables in my database, it was very helpful.